# Fortran runtime error: Bad value on logical read

Tags: fortran, fortran90

When gfortran reads the input file, it shows this error:

```
Fortran runtime error: Bad value on logical read
```

My code is:

---

```
SUBROUTINE GRIDGN
  USE NINETY
  IMPLICIT NONE
  DOUBLE PRECISION::SCF
  REAL, DIMENSION (100):: Z 

  READ(unit=5,FMT=100) LSTORE,LCALG,LPRINT,LPLOT,LAXIS
  READ(5,*) NGR
  READ(5,*) IDIR
  100 FORMAT (L1,L1,L1,L1,L1)
```

---

The input file starts with:

```
T T T T F  LSTORE,LCALG,LPRINT,LPLOT,LAXIS
```

I have declared the `LSTORE,LCALG,LPRINT,LPLOT,LAXIS` as `LOGICAL` in the `NINETY` module.

Anyone of you knows why the error occurs?

Comment: change the format to `100 FORMAT ( 5(L1,1X) )` or write the input file as : `TTTTF`. the program expect no space.

Comment: Or use list-directed input on read (ie `read(*,*)`).  It's generally a lot more robust.

Comment: Thanks  M. Chinoune and High Performance Mark for the reply. What are the rules that I should follow while writing an input list for fortran 90?